# Unexpected password authentication problem

Tags: debian, password, authentication

I have been using a properly configured system with no authentication changes for over a month now. And suddenly I get this error message:

```
Sorry, password authentication didn't work. Please try again.
```

This is despite the fact that there has been no changes to the password.

My OS is Debian 12 bookworm. I did observe that my system downloaded gnome-software during last successful login. But after the reboot I get the same message "sorry..." for both correct and incorrect passwords. I tried for root user too to no avail.

Can anyone please share the exact reason for this failure? Please note, the error doesn't say that the password is incorrect. I want to know what could possibly cause the process of authentication to not work (as the message states so); what is happening here?

Comment: 2 Questions: 1. so you can log in successfully and still get the message?^^ 2. Also random idea, but maybe check your diskspace with `df`. Unlikely that this is the problem, but it is possible^^

Comment: Hey, thank you! I had to change the password to login again. I shall continue the research though.